# VS 2012 web express doesn't compile typescript files on existing ASP MVC projects

Tags: typescript

So I've set up VS 2012 web express to compile typescript by installing the microsoft 0.8.2 extension, but nothing happens on save, ie not .js files or source map file generated.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot; -module amd -target ES5 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run the command manually with command prompt - this is the best way of testing the command...

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc" --module amd --target ES5 YourFile.ts
```

(note the flags are normally double dashed)

You should discover one of the following...

- The TypeScript compiler is in a different location to the one you are using
- There is a compiler error that is stopping the JavaScript files from being generated

Comment: I found that RequireJs was caching the old js file :)

Comment: I recently tried adding this to a exisiting Asp Mvc 4 project:    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot; -module amd -target ES5 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />  but the files are not compiled, however running this on a file in this mvc project results in a successful compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript>tsc --module amd --target ES5
D:\WebUI\Typescripts\Alerts.ts
 Any ideas mate?

Comment: This works on items passed using the TypeScriptCompile sections in the project file - so check to see if you have at least one of those (normally it would point to app.ts, for example)

Comment: ahh. hopefully microsoft will add those automatically in future! cheers again Steve for what your doing for the ts community